# If dataGridView value is not null then XX not working as intended

Tags: c#, datagridview

Inside a button click I have this code which inserts the text from a combobox into column C:

```
private void updateExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
             if  (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value != null)
             {
                for (int ii = 0; ii < dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; ii++)
                {
                    dataGridView1[2, ii].Value = ConsigneeCombo.Text;
                }
                break;
             }
        }
    }
}
```

When its ran it should only put the value on rows with a value in column A of the row, but it is repeating the value inserted on all rows.

Comment: Isn't this something that should (relatively) easily be discovered and fixed by using a debugger, stepping through the code, putting breakpoints, inspecting variable values, and the like?

Comment: I've tried multiple combinations of ifs to get this to work but it keeps repeating.

Comment: Do not use trial and error! Use the debugger!!! Also: What is 'XX' ??? You are using two different DGVs on purpose, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted loop and the logic do not look correct in reference to what you what to do….

> … *”it should only put the value on rows with a value in column A of
>   the row”* ….

Currently the code, uses one `for` loop to loop through all the “rows” in the grid...

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
```

Then another `for` loop to loop through all the “columns” in the grid…

```
 for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
```

This is going to loop through ALL the cells in the grid…
    IF One of the cells in the grid is NOT null …

```
 if  (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value != null)
```

Then (AGAIN?) loop through ALL the "rows" and set the third columns value in that row to the value contained in the combo box…. ?

This doesn’t sound like what you want. The “break” statement is simply going to skip the columns “after” the “first” value is found. This logic is not going to achieve what you are asking.

Therefore, to simplify

*”it should only put the value on rows with a value in column A of the row”*

This implies we only need to loop through all the rows. It is not necessary to loop through the columns and we only need to do this loop once. Logic being…

Loop through all the rows, in each row, if there is a “value” in column A (0), then add the combo box text to column C (2). This logic may look something like below.

```
private void updateExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++) {
    if (!dataGridView1.Rows[i].IsNewRow &&
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value != null &&
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() != "") {
      dataGridView1[2, i].Value = ConsigneeCombo.Text;
    }
  }
}
```

This will only add the combo box text to the third column if the value in the first column is NOT empty.

Comment: Works perfect!!